# reference to dynamically allocated object ("at run-time")

Tags: c++, reference, initialization

Essentially I have a lot of code that was written assuming a file-level static would be a struct. So all references are like **struct.member**.

I've had to make a change to this code and make that a **static struct *** and allocate this struct at run-time.

I wanted to create a reference **struct& ref = *myStatic** as I'm lazy and don't want to change A TON of **struct.member** to **struct->member**.

But references need be initialized when they're declared (right?) and I only know what I want it to refer to at run-time. Is this possible?

*(in case it's confusing.. i'm using the word struct in place of my actual struct name, not as the literal c++ struct keyword)*

Comment: Just change them. Future coders (including yourself!) could hate you for not doing so.

Comment: Following what GManNickG said, your editor probably has built-in macros for Find/Replace functions.

Comment: :) yes.. was just trying to prove a prototype to myself before going all the way.

Answer (score 1):

***"references need be initialized when they're declared (right?)"***

The object that reference will be initialized with must exist at the time when the reference is created [1], which in this case exists:

```
MyStruct* s = new MyStruct;
MyStruct& ref = *s;
```

this dynamically allocates memory for object of type `MyStruct`, then constructs this object and at the end it creates a reference `ref` to this object. It's perfectly fine as long as you are careful with the lifetime of `s`. Reference will become invalid once the memory where `s` resided is deallocated.

Although decision whether you will or will not use a reference should not be based on you feeling lazy about replacing `.` with `->`.

---

[1]  C++03 Standard **8.3.2 §4**: *"A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object
or function."*